# yaml generation in Java

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am new to Java and I am having issue to generate a yaml. I want to generate a yaml file through java like below and I have used snake yaml for this purpose.

```
mart:
  details:
    name: Koushik
    purpose: yaml generation for testing
    owner:
      - name: Bobby
        email: bd@abc.com
      - name: Chaminda
        email: cv@def.com
```

tried with something like below, but not achieving the yaml the way I am expecting.

```
public class yamlGeneration {

   public static String get_details() {
     String name = "Koushik";
     String purpose = "yaml generation for testing";

     String notification_name_1 = "Bobby";
     String notification_email_1 = "bd@abc.com";
     String notification_name_2 = "Chaminda";
     String notification_email_2 = "cv@def.com";

     Map<String, Object> notification = new LinkedHashMap<>();
     List<Map<String, Object>> owner = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
     notification.put("name",notification_name_1);
     notification.put("email",notification_email_1);
     owner.add(notification);
     notification.put("name",notification_name_2);
     notification.put("email",notification_email_2);
     owner.add(notification);

     Map<String, Object> details = new LinkedHashMap<>();
     details.put("name",name);
     details.put("purpose",purpose);
     details.put("owner",owner);

     Map<String, Object> mart = new LinkedHashMap<>();
     mart.put("details",details);

     Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
     return yaml.dump(mart).toString();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
     String str = get_details();
     System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: *"not achieving the yaml the way I am expecting"* - you'll need to include this information in the question, nobody's going to run through hoops to run your example just to see HOW it behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the proper styling, you need to create and configure a [`DumperOptions`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/org/yaml/snakeyaml/DumperOptions.html) object and pass it to the constructor of the `Yaml` class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> root = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> mart = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    Map<String, Object> details = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    details.put("name", "Koushik");
    details.put("purpose", "yaml generation for testing");
    details.put("owner", Arrays.asList(
            Map.of("name", "Bobby", "email", "bd@abc.com"),
            Map.of("name", "Chaminda", "email", "cv@def.com")
    ));

    mart.put("details", details);
    root.put("mart", mart);

    DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
    options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
    System.out.println(yaml.dump(root));
}
```

**Output:**

```
mart:
  details:
    name: Koushik
    purpose: yaml generation for testing
    owner:
    - name: Bobby
      email: bd@abc.com
    - name: Chaminda
      email: cv@def.com
```

Additionaly, you could create [`Representer`s](https://static.javadoc.io/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/org/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer.html) and [`Resolver`s](https://static.javadoc.io/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/org/yaml/snakeyaml/resolver/Resolver.html) so that you can use custom classes instead of nested `Map`s.

Comment: owner is an array here. Though I did hard coded the values, but practically the data will be fetched db tables; so it can be a variable number of elements. In your solution, could you please let me know how could I fill variable number of elements for owner?

Comment: @KoushikChandra I think this is a totally differnt question, isn't it? Maybe you should open a new question for that and provide an example because I'm not totally sure what you mean.